# Banco de dados SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Opa galera eu estou tentando "brincar" com um banco de dados no android studio. Eu criei esse código abaixo... quando eu executo ele o simulador abre a já fecha sozinho logo em seguida. eu inclui o log.i no programa dentro do laço de repetição para que eu, a nível de teste excluísse a linha logo abaixo do

> `log.i (vaiqcolanome[i]=cursor.getString(nome);`

a linha em questão seria apenas para armazenar as informações da varredura no banco dentro de um Array. quando eu tiro essa linha as informações do meu banco estão aparecendo na lista de log, logo acho q o que não está funcionando direito é simplesmente a atribuição dos dados do banco na Array "vaiqcolanome". 
o programa:

```
package com.example.bancodados;

    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lista;
String vaiqcolanome[];

int vaiqcolaidade[];
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lista=findViewById(R.id.lista);
    String listaaa[]={"Thiago","Vanessa"};

    SQLiteDatabase database = openOrCreateDatabase("meuapp",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS listadepessoas (nome VARCHAR, idade INT(3))");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO listadepessoas (nome,idade) VALUES('Thiago',31)");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO listadepessoas (nome,idade) VALUES('Vanessa',32)");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO listadepessoas (nome,idade) VALUES('Alice',5)");

    final Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT nome, idade FROM listadepessoas",null);
    final int nome = cursor.getColumnIndex("nome");
    int idade = cursor.getColumnIndex("idade");

    cursor.moveToFirst();


    int i =0;



    while(i<1) {


        Log.i("Logx",cursor.getString(nome));
        vaiqcolanome[i]=cursor.getString(nome);

        cursor.moveToNext();
        i++;
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            getApplication(),
            android.R.layout.activity_list_item,
            android.R.id.text1,
            vaiqcolanome
    );
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

}

Comment: Cara, deve estar dando alguma exceção, faça o seguinte, coloca m try-catch de um Throwable do método inteiro e ve o que printa de erro e corrija

Comment: vlw man... rodei no try catch e as Array não podem ser nulas... então fui obrigado a começar elas com qualquer valor para poder rodar o código...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas duas variáveis não são inicializadas, vai dar nullpointer.

```
String vaiqcolanome[];
int vaiqcolaidade[];
```

Comment: Realmente Felipe. fiz o que tu me indicou no comentário anterior e deu nisso... brigado duas vezes ^^

Comment: Que bom que pude ajudar! :)